# What defines the width of my div element?

Tags: html, css

CSS. Never my strong point!

Consider the following styling:

```
  .popupComponentContent{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    padding: 16px;
    max-height:100vh;
    max-width:100vw;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color:white;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:auto;
  }
```

noting that there are no specific rules for the width or the height of the targeted element.

Let's apply this styling to the following markup:

```
<div class="popupComponentContent" > 
  <p>
    This is a popup!
  </p>
</div>
```

And the outer div fits nicely around the content. See example on codepen [right here](http://codepen.io/spender/full/qZRKJo/).

Now, instead, let's apply it to this markup:

```
<div class="popupComponentContent" > 
  <p>
    This is a popup!
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus gravida eget 
     dolor a interdum. Donec placerat turpis ac lacinia rhoncus. Cras urna magna, 
     imperdiet ut imperdiet ultrices, euismod non elit. Proin vel metus pretium, 
     bibendum tortor vel, congue quam. Sed ultrices lacus quam, nec porttitor 
     mi scelerisque eget. Praesent accumsan varius leo nec tincidunt. Maecenas 
     viverra ultricies purus quis rutrum.</p>
</div>
```

...ensuring that we have enough content to cover the width of the viewport. See example on codepen [right here](http://codepen.io/spender/full/pyRKGE/).

Why is the div in the second example half the width of the screen? What makes that happen? Why doesn't it extend to the full width of the screen?

Comment: the elements have standard values set by the browsers that work when no values are stipulated. 'css reset' and 'normalize.css' are made to let these values equal in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've applied `.popupComponentContent` to a div which is a block element. It covers 100% of the screen (parent element) unless a width is specified.

In `.popupComponentContent`, you use `left: 50%`. This doesn't actually position the element at where it supposed to be since the element is a block with no width specified. It basically shrinks the div. Right side of the div is snapped to right. `left: 50%` just moves the left side of the div to `50%`, so you get 50% width for your div.

If you want to move your div to `left: 50%` while preserving its default width (which is 100%), you should apply `display:table` on the div.

So I'd say `display:block` on the div defines the width.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `transform` line and the `left` line will make it display full width.

As it is, it covers only 50 percent because `left: 50%;` bumps the left margin halfway across the window, then `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` bumps the whole element back across the window the other way.

Comment: I know that. It's not what I asked. I want to know why it covers only 50% width with the rules as they are currently applied.

Comment: It covers only 50 percent, because `left: 50%;` bumps the left margin halfway across the window, then `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` bumps the whole element back across the window the other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `transform` attribute to understand it. If you do that you'll see the width of **the element fits with the remaining space between `left: 50%` and the right side**.

So you can play with this `left` attribute to adjust the maximum width for your popup (as well as adjusting the transform to keep it centered).

Take a look on flexbox, it can help you to improve this.